# Rhythmbox doesn't launch linux mint Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

Tags: linux-mint, rhythmbox

when i click on rythmbox he doent start i tried to open it from terminal

```
abdou@abdou:~$ rhythmbox %U
Bus error
```

I thought the probleme from app it self so searched for alternative to rhythmbox . i installed Strawberry Music Player and guess what even strawberry doesnt start

```
 abdou@abdou:~$ strawberry %U
19:25:18.415 INFO  main:167                         Strawberry 0.8.5
19:25:18.479 INFO  main:168                         "Linux Mint 20.1 20.1 - (linux 5.4.0-65-generic) [x86_64]"
19:25:18.953 DEBUG unknown                          using qt5ct plugin 
19:25:19.810 DEBUG main:209                         Style: "qt5ct-style"
19:25:20.110 DEBUG Application:254                  Database(0x5569a8ccd770) moved to thread QThread(0x5569a8cd1e60)
19:25:20.125 DEBUG SCollection:63                   CollectionBackend(0x5569a8ccc3c0) moved to thread QThread(0x5569a8cd1e60)
19:25:20.731 DEBUG Application:254                  AlbumCoverLoader(0x5569a8d4e720) moved to thread QThread(0x5569a8d553b0)
19:25:20.857 DEBUG SCollection:95                   CollectionWatcher(0x5569a8d5b2a0) moved to thread QThread(0x5569a8d58130)
19:25:20.893 DEBUG Application:254                  TagReaderClient(0x5569a8bc1e00) moved to thread QThread(0x5569a8d5af40)
19:25:20.894 DEBUG NetworkProxyFactory:55           Detected system proxy URLs: ("", "", "", "")
19:25:20.894 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:287      Starting worker 0x7f4d43ffded0 "/usr/bin/strawberry-tagreader" "/tmp/strawberry_1091447190"
19:25:20.899 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:287      Starting worker 0x7f4d43ffded0 "/usr/bin/strawberry-tagreader" "/tmp/strawberry_1438171964"
Bus error
abdou@abdou:~$ 19:25:26.492 INFO  main:56                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/strawberry_1091447190"
19:25:26.492 INFO  main:56                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/strawberry_1438171964"
Failed to connect to the parent process.
Failed to connect to the parent process.
```

here is my system details :

```
abdou@abdou:~$ inxi -Fxz

  System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-65-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
```

The output of sudo dpkg -l | grep rhythmbox:

```
ii  gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64                        3.4.4-1ubuntu2                              amd64        GObject introspection data for the rhythmbox music player
ii  librhythmbox-core10:amd64                  3.4.4-1ubuntu2                              amd64        support library for the rhythmbox music player
ii  rhythmbox                                  3.4.4-1ubuntu2                              amd64        music player and organizer for GNOME
ii  rhythmbox-data                             3.4.4-1ubuntu2                              all          data files for rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar       0.19.3-1.1                                  all          Enhanced play controls and interface for Rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-plugins                          3.4.4-1ubuntu2                              amd64        plugins for rhythmbox music player
```

help please! thank you

Comment: Looks like it probably has something to do with `dbus`

Comment: do you  know how to fix it ?